# Magento 2.4.5 unable to run any command because of error

Tags: magento2, php8

When I try to execute any magento command it gives me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Interception\ConfigLoaderInterface in /home/vagrant/code/%PROJECT%/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
```

As you can see in the error message I am using a vagrant box to try and get my project running locally. Just did a composer update and magento update to 2.4.5. Can't get the project to work without updating either. I am using php 8.1, php-fpm 8.1 and magento package:
`magento/product-community-edition: 2.4.5`

My di.xml does contain the line:

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Interception\ConfigLoaderInterface" type="Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator" />
```

Also tried to use the di.xml from https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.3-release/app/etc/di.xml

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons and solutions you can do to steps to reproduce:

1: Check your app/etc/di.xml and you need to match your di.xml with the latest Magento 2.4.5 release.

2: Also backup your vendor folder and:
rm -rf vendor/*
composer clearcache
composer install
then compile magento and run command like (setup upgrade.... cache flush)

3: Try below commands:

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

rm -Rf var/view_proccessed rm -Rf var/cache rm -Rf pub/static/frontend
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f php bin/magento c:f or php bin/magento cache:flush

Reproducing your custom module **vagrant** may create some errors while compiling the code.

4: Also add this preference in your module (vagrant) di.xml, i.e., might use a dependency with Config loader.

5: Also clear the cache, i.e, also Redis cache (If use)